# UI Elements are not visible in Fullscreen mode

Tags: android, fullscreen, google-vr, android-immersive, vrvideoview

I'm trying to view a `ImageButton` (play and pause) when a `video` is shown in `fullscreen` mode of `Google VR`, but they are not `visible`.
The `button` is visible only in `non-fullscreen` mode.

**The things I've tried:**

- Add the `view` after the `fullscreen` mode is entered
- Try to leave `immersive` mode for current `decorView`
- Changing `ImageButtons` visibility
- Trying to get the `ImageButton` to front with `bringToFront()`

Unfortunately nothing works.